# Swift3 Multiple buttons dynamic coding to trigger event

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, storyboard, iboutlet

I have multiple buttons. Each button contains a language label.

I want to make it so that when users tap on the button, the selected language label changes its value according to the button tapped.

The selected language outlet is called SelectedLangText.

A simple solution would be to create multiple Action outlets for each button and set the value of SelectedLangText label. However, if there would be 100 buttons, that would be bad coding.

I'm not sure how to approach this situation in Swift 3 coming from web development.

[image]

Comment: You should try creating the tableView using dynamic content instead of static content. That would allow you to support an unlimited amount of languages. Word of advice use lower camel case when typing variable names and methods in iOS. I'll write up an answer in a sec. I'm working with the assumption that you know how to work with the UITableViewDataSource and that you know how to create a custom cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using the delegate design pattern when it comes to solving an issue like that for it I find it to be a much cleaner approach than just a mass amount of @IBActions

1- Create a Language class
import Foundation

```
class Language {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

2- Create the custom cell in the storyboard or nib and then add the appropriate outlets and actions. And then you create a Delegate protocol for it

```
import UIKit
protocol CustomCellDelegate: class {
    func customCell(newLanguageSelected language: Language)
}
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var language: Language!
    @IBOutlet weak var languageTextLabel: UILabel!
    weak var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
    func setupCustomCell(withLanguage language: Language){
        self.language = language
        self.languageTextLabel.text = self.language.name
    }
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton){
        delegate?.customCell(newLanguageSelected: self.language)
    }
}
```

3- Finally add the implementation in the cellForRow method of the UITableViewDataSource and add the implementation of the delegate in the UITableViewController class

```
import UIKit
class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController{
    var languages: [Language] = []

    //implement the other methods in the dataSource

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuse", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.setupCustomCell(withLanguage: languages[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
extension YourTableViewController: CustomCellDelegate{
    func customCell(newLanguageSelected language: Language) {
        //Do what you will with the language
    }
}
```

Good luck

Comment: This looks like extreme overkill for something so small of a task. Do I really need this much code?

Comment: This is the right way to do it if you want to have a lot of cells. And it also better for people who reading the code. It provides a more elegant and clear cut approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can add Tags to each button and Set same IBAction for all buttons.

First in your method get the language based on the button.
Now use loop(go with for loop as you will need proper index for each button) and get all buttons from its tag and set language tag.

A bit complex at glance, but will solve your problem and good solution in my eye.

```
for index in 101...103 {
        let myBtn = self.view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton
        myBtn.setTitle("localisedtitle string", for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Where can I add the tags? Is it identifier?

Comment: Sorry I'm really stuck on where to start. I haven't actually learnt Swift yet. Could you provide an example code snippet?

Comment: In interface builder, In buttons property.... or you can generate buttons run time as well if you have many records or just go with table view.

Comment: @ThomasCharlesworth, if you are in hurry I can provide code snippet. but I suggest you try your best once.

Comment: anyway sending you snippet to get buttons with tag in swift 3 in next 5 min

Comment: Edited answer with the snippet to get a button... create a single method and set an action for all your button.. add this code in your method... I hope you are getting this now.

Comment: I think you mis understood the question.